# Meteor - how to get response from payment REST API

Tags: rest, meteor, payment, notify, payu

I'm implementing PayU payment module in my Meteor app. Flow works well, it shows proper order view and it redirects to proper *continueUrl*. In PayU API there is also *notifyUrl* and PayU can send POST request to that url if there is change in order's status. When there is, for example COMPLETED status I should execute update in mongoDB and change user's account type.

But I don't have any idea how to make it. Should I make html file on meteor's server side? If it's possible what link should I pass in *notifyUrl* to make PayU request pass to that html file?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with the [HTTP](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http)? package? something like this.

First add it.

```
meteor add http
```

Then create a method like this.

```
Meteor.methods({
  someMethodName: function() {
    return HTTP.call("POST", "http://payuIrl", {
        data: {
          idk "data",
            stuff: JSON.stringify(myObject);
        }
      });
  }
});
```

and then on the client you can create a Meteor.call on the client.

```
Meteor.call('someMethodName',function(erro,result){
 if(error){
   //show some error
  }else{
   if(_.isEqual(result.status,'status200'){
      //run update here
    }
  }
});
```

Or you can run the update on the server without the `Meteor.methods` and `Meteor.calls`